# Wordpress init / plugins_loaded hooks fired multiple times

Tags: php, wordpress, macos

Newly installed Wordpress 5.5.1 with default theme 2020.
Add very short plugin (there is no other code in it):

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', function () {
    error_log('plugins_loaded fired!');
    error_log('here do something after plugins_loaded...');
});

add_action('init', function () {
    error_log('init fired!');
    error_log('here do something after init...');
});
```

What I've seen in debug.log:

```
[18-Oct-2020 16:20:01 UTC] plugins_loaded fired!
[18-Oct-2020 16:20:01 UTC] here do something after plugins_loaded...
[18-Oct-2020 16:20:03 UTC] plugins_loaded fired!
[18-Oct-2020 16:20:03 UTC] here do something after plugins_loaded...
[18-Oct-2020 16:20:04 UTC] init fired!
[18-Oct-2020 16:20:04 UTC] here do something after init...
[18-Oct-2020 16:20:07 UTC] plugins_loaded fired!
[18-Oct-2020 16:20:07 UTC] here do something after plugins_loaded...
[18-Oct-2020 16:20:07 UTC] init fired!
[18-Oct-2020 16:20:07 UTC] here do something after init...
[18-Oct-2020 16:20:09 UTC] init fired!
[18-Oct-2020 16:20:09 UTC] here do something after init...
```

What??
Please bear in mind - there is no other code, there is no other pages except exist in 2020 theme, just one plugin activated (this one). So, I could not force such abnormal behavior.

Comment: `init fired!` is fired 3 times in 10 seconds, which is not that many, are you working on local or on a server?

Comment: @MarcelloPerri: These hooks should be fired ONCE as it is written in doc. This log collected at localhost, but for server looks the same

Comment: What do you mean with fired once? What do you expect to see in the logs?

Comment: @MarcelloPerri: I expect to see just one log record for init and the same for plugins_loaded

Comment: I don't think that's the way WordPress works. The hook init is fired anytime a page is loaded. According to the documentation init is perfect to intercept Get and Post which means that it's fired anytime a page is called.

Comment: @MarcelloPerri: to perform correct initialization for my plugin, I need to use hook fired just once during Wordpress session lifetime. What hook it could be?

Comment: Does your plugin working properly? I would connect your plugin main function with the hook init. That's all you need to do. Please have a read at this article https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch--net-2668

Comment: I can't use 'init' hook to initialize plugin - initialization in my case it's a thing performed once at site level, but 'init' hook as you can see is fired more times. So, 'init' usage is bad idea

Answer (score 2):

[Valery Bulash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1895410/valery-bulash), Hope you have this solved by now since this thread is 3 years old. Also posting this answer in case anyone else winds up here with the same question.

Please know that any request to any WordPress url will load plugins and other core WP stuff.

For example, if you're testing your plugin while you have the WP admin open, note that there is an AJAX call made every so often to `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. So if you're seeing duplicate log entries, it could be because of that.

Also note that if you have several tabs open (One with a front-end page, one with an admin page, etc.) Each will also cause WordPress to load as each tab has made a request.

If you want to verify, you should add the request url to your test log entries. At the very least this should help you figure out where your plugin code is being called from.

```php
add_action('plugins_loaded', function () {
    error_log('plugins_loaded fired!');
    error_log($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    error_log('here do something after plugins_loaded...');
});
```

Should yield something like:

```text
[13-Feb-2023 15:45:54 UTC] plugins_loaded fired!
[13-Feb-2023 15:45:54 UTC] /wp-admin/index.php
[13-Feb-2023 15:45:54 UTC] here do something after plugins_loaded...
[13-Feb-2023 15:46:02 UTC] plugins_loaded fired!
[13-Feb-2023 15:46:02 UTC] /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
[13-Feb-2023 15:46:02 UTC] here do something after plugins_loaded...
[13-Feb-2023 15:47:02 UTC] plugins_loaded fired!
[13-Feb-2023 15:47:02 UTC] /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
[13-Feb-2023 15:47:02 UTC] here do something after plugins_loaded...
```